# Python For Loop slowing down after increasing iterations

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand why a loop would slow down after increasing iterations. This code is just a simulation of some actual code that replicates data from an API. I have to download data in batched because if I do it all at once, I run out of memory. However, my loop implementation for the batches is not very optimal. I suspect that using pandas is increasing overhead but besides that, what else could be causing the problem?

```
import timeit
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm


def some_generator():
    for i in range(1_000_000):
        yield {
            'colA': 'valA',
            'colB': 'valA',
            'colC': 'valA',
            'colD': 'valA',
            'colE': 'valA',
            'colF': 'valA',
            'colG': 'valA',
            'colH': 'valA',
            'colI': 'valA',
            'colJ': 'valA'
        }


def main():
    batch_size = 10_000
    generator = some_generator()
    output = pd.DataFrame()
    batch_round = 1

    while True:

        for _ in tqdm(range(batch_size), desc=f"Batch {batch_round}"):

            try:
                row = next(generator)
                row.pop('colA')
                output = pd.concat([output, pd.DataFrame(row, index=[0])], ignore_index=True)

            except StopIteration:
                break

        if output.shape[0] != batch_size * batch_round:
            break
        else:
            batch_round += 1

    print(output)
```

This code is simulating a 1M row dataframe, if I download data in batches of 10k, this is the performance I get for the first 20 batches.

```
Batch 1: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:21<00:00, 460.89it/s]
Batch 2: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:28<00:00, 349.16it/s]
Batch 3: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:38<00:00, 263.12it/s]
Batch 4: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:43<00:00, 228.76it/s]
Batch 5: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:53<00:00, 187.44it/s]
Batch 6: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [01:02<00:00, 159.92it/s]
Batch 7: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [01:09<00:00, 144.79it/s]
Batch 8: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [01:18<00:00, 127.59it/s]
Batch 9: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [01:25<00:00, 116.92it/s]
Batch 10: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [01:34<00:00, 105.96it/s]
Batch 11: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [01:40<00:00, 99.81it/s]
Batch 12: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [01:46<00:00, 93.92it/s]
Batch 13: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [01:55<00:00, 86.49it/s]
Batch 14: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [02:03<00:00, 80.92it/s]
Batch 15: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [02:10<00:00, 76.46it/s]
Batch 16: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [02:18<00:00, 71.99it/s]
Batch 17: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [02:25<00:00, 68.69it/s]
Batch 18: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [02:32<00:00, 65.57it/s]
Batch 19: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [02:42<00:00, 61.53it/s]
Batch 20: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [02:39<00:00, 62.84it/s]
```

Comment: Of course it is. `output = pd.concat([output, ...])` is a linear time operation, making that loop overall quadratic. Don't do this. Accumulate the intermediate result in a list and do one final `pd.concat`

Comment: Each loop is forced to copy an increasingly large dataset, so it makes sense each loop will take progressively more time.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you made my life easier today, thank you! Where can I read more about time/space complexity? Honestly, that was not important to me until today lol So, I imagine I might have other silly mistakes like this in other projects. Appreciate any recommendations, cheers!

Comment: @Shogun187 if you look it up you should find a lot of resources. Also, any good computer science textbook on algorithms will go through this. While you don't have to go deep into the mathematics of it, it is good to acquire an intuition about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pd.Concat is expensive ->

Here, what you can do - use an empty list and append row dict to that particular list. Finally, convert the output back to pandas dataframe after all the manipulations. It'll be super fast this way :)

```
import timeit
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm


def some_generator():
    for _ in range(1_000_000):
        yield {
            'colA': 'valA',
            'colB': 'valA',
            'colC': 'valA',
            'colD': 'valA',
            'colE': 'valA',
            'colF': 'valA',
            'colG': 'valA',
            'colH': 'valA',
            'colI': 'valA',
            'colJ': 'valA'
        }


def main():
    batch_size = 10_000
    generator = some_generator()
    output = []
    batch_round = 1

    while True:

        for _ in tqdm(range(batch_size), desc=f"Batch {batch_round}"):

            try:
                row = next(generator)
                row.pop('colA')
                output.append(row)

            except for StopIteration:
                break

        shape = len(output)  
        if shape != batch_size * batch_round:
            break
        else:
            batch_round += 1
            

    # print(pd.DataFrame(output))

main()
```

**Output -**

```
Batch 1: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 826724.48it/s]
Batch 2: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 978765.55it/s]
Batch 3: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1072629.72it/s]
Batch 4: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1267237.90it/s]
Batch 5: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1351301.27it/s]
Batch 6: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1402918.02it/s]
Batch 7: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1374370.54it/s]
Batch 8: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1435520.57it/s]
Batch 9: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1499947.79it/s]
Batch 10: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1458381.08it/s]
Batch 11: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1366178.30it/s]
Batch 12: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1396844.17it/s]
Batch 13: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1376309.76it/s]
Batch 14: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1453881.94it/s]
Batch 15: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1373245.59it/s]
Batch 16: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1470756.72it/s]
Batch 17: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1450964.82it/s]
Batch 18: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1495882.16it/s]
Batch 19: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1477960.46it/s]
Batch 20: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1479733.29it/s]
Batch 21: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1383528.17it/s]
Batch 22: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1361521.78it/s]
Batch 23: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1420594.07it/s]
Batch 24: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1468850.99it/s]
Batch 25: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1477960.46it/s]
Batch 26: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1055755.13it/s]
Batch 27: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 952104.06it/s]
Batch 28: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1260231.96it/s]
Batch 29: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1433705.01it/s]
Batch 30: 100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 1404703.44it/s]
```

Comment: I second this answer, I use a similar technique at my workplace

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up implementing and works perfect when replicating data from the API server. Went from running a job for multiple hours to a few minutes. I would like to know why `pd.concat` is an expensive operation? I saw someone comment that pd.concat is O(n) and the for loop is also O(n) so it gets to quadratic complexity. Why is pd.concat considered O(n)?